# What is the difference between Font Awesome 4 and 5?

Tags: fonts, icons, difference, font-awesome-5, font-awesome-4

Could you please write me : what is the difference between Font Awesome 4 and 5?

and what is the difference between :

```html
<i class="fas fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Thank You !

Answer (score 0):

Font Awesome 5 is a big refactoring of Font Awesome including new icons and breaking changes.

`fas` FontAwesome CSS class stands for **f**ont **a**wesome **s**olid (the Solid icon style) but `fa` is also kept for retro-compatibility. So, there is no difference between `fas` an `fa` that both applies the Solid icon style.

Regarding the differences between Font Awesome 4 and 5 :

- 5 icons styles (Solid, Brands, Regular, Light and Duotone) but only the first two are free (Solid and Brands)
- some icons have new names
- now all icons have an "outlined" style but this is in the Regular icon style which is not free. As a consequence, icons previously ending by `-o` does not exist anymore in FontAwesome version 5 Free.

Also have a look at the page [Upgrade From Version 4](https://fontawesome.com/v5/docs/web/setup/upgrade-from-v4#what-s-changed-from-version-4-to-5) of Font Awesome docs for more info.